# Django value error. model field must be an instance

Tags: python, django

I get an error when testing address model. This user is suppose to enter address information before getting billed, but it produces a value error that states that the billing field in address model must be an instance of the billing model. This shouldn't be because i already associated the billing model to address model by foreign key.

For clarity, here the names for the actual models:
`BillingProfile` and `Addresses`

here is the error produced:

```
ValueError at /cart/checkout/address/create

Cannot assign "(<BillingProfile: romeo@gmail.com>, False)": "Address.billing_profile" must be a "BillingProfile" instance.
```

Here is my address view.
Error at line 24.

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import AddressForm
from billing.models import BillingProfile
from django.utils.http import is_safe_url

def checkout_address_create(request):
    form = AddressForm(request.POST or None)
    context = {
        'form':form
    }

    next_post = request.POST.get('next')
    redirect_path = next_post or None

    if form.is_valid():
        print(request.POST)
        instance = form.save(commit=False)

        billing_profile = BillingProfile.objects.new_or_get(request)
        print(billing_profile)
        address_type = request.POST.get('address_type', 'shipping')

        if billing_profile is not None:
            instance.billing_profile = billing_profile # Value error at billing
            instance.address_type = address_type
            instance.save()
            print('Form saved')
        else:
            print('Error: NO billing profile')
            return redirect('cart:checkout')

        if is_safe_url(redirect_path, request.get_host()):
            return redirect(redirect_path)
        else:
            return redirect('cart:checkout')
    return redirect('cart:checkout')
```

Here are the address and billing models.
Address:

```
from django.db import models
from billing.models import BillingProfile

ADDRESS_TYPES = (('billing', 'billing'),('shipping', 'shipping'))

class Address(models.Model):
    billing_profile = models.ForeignKey(BillingProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=120, default='Nigeria')
    state = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    address_type = models.CharField(max_length=120, choices=ADDRESS_TYPES)
    address_line1 = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    address_line2 = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.BillingProfile)
```

Billing;

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

from accounts.models import Guest
User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

class BillingProfileManager(models.Manager):
    def new_or_get(self, request):
        user = request.user
        guest_email_id = request.session.get('guest_email_id')
        obj = None
        created = False

         # Logged in user checkout. Remembers payment
        if user.is_authenticated:
            obj,created = self.model.objects.get_or_create(user=user, email=user.email)
            # Guest user checkout. autoreloads payment
        elif guest_email_id is not None:
            guest_obj = Guest
            guest_email_obj = guest_obj.objects.get(id=guest_email_id)
            obj,created = self.model.objects.get_or_create(email=guest_email_obj.email)
            created = True
        else:
            created = False
        return obj, created

class BillingProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, unique=True, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
    email = models.EmailField()
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    update = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    timestamp = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)

    objects = BillingProfileManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

def user_created_reciever(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created and instance.email:
        BillingProfile.objects.get_or_create(user=instance, email=instance.email)
post_save.connect(user_created_reciever, sender=User)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, needs a simple fix. `objects.new_or_get()` returns a tuple with an object and a boolean. In your case `(<BillingProfile: romeo@gmail.com>, False)`. The boolean indicates whether the value is newly created or not.

Fix it by getting the first element of the tuple:

```
billing_profile = BillingProfile.objects.new_or_get(request)[0]
```

Comment: yes, it makes sense now, it does return tuple of object and boolean. thanks for the help. @engin_ipek

Comment: I have the very same problem and this answer is still rocking SERP, but I am having a `AttributeError: 'Manager' object has no attribute 'new_or_get'`
I am doing something on the sort of: 

`models.Invoice.objects.create(sender=models.Company.objects.new_or_get(request)[0]`

am i wrong? @engin_ipek